# ruby on rails, redirect if hitting back button in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, reload, back-button, search-form

I have a searchform which displays available rooms to book, if i book a room and hit the back button in my browser afterwards, the searchresults are still displayed. Is it possible to reload the page when i hit back, so that the user has to click on the searchbutton again to see the available rooms? I just want the default searchform without the results? 
I tried this before:

```
before_filter :set_cache_buster
def set_cache_buster
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    response.headers["Expires"] = "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
 end
```

but this just reloads the page with the users input paramteres still in the search, so it basically shows the same page as without reloading, 
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your form method is "GET", the page is always available when you hit back button and the query strings are all in url. In many cases this effect is preferred, for example you can bookmark a Google search url.

You can change form method as "POST" so the page will not be available again.

**Add**

Use this with a bit caution. In convention "GET" is meant to get data and "POST" is meant to add some data. A search form is built for get data so the convention of form method is "GET", nothing wrong here. So only change it if you really need to that.

**Add more** OP said he can't change form method

Well, here is a hack, if you want search result to appear to only on click of button, instead of url with params.

The idea is to use Javascript to attach a new hidden input when clicking button, then controller verify if this new param exists. If exists, process and return result, else show some error.

```
# JavaScript
$('#the_form button').on('submit', function() {
  this.preventDefault();
  this.parent.append('<input type="hidden" name="human_hit" value="yes" />');
  this.parent.submit();
})

# Controller
def search
  if params[:human_hit]
    # Do search logic and deliver
  else
    redirect_to :back, alert: "You need to hit the button to search"
  end
end
```

This is a hack and not verified, the idea should be able to do the trick.

Comment: yeah but I can't change the method because otherwise my search wouldn't work

Comment: Why do you want to disable the search when going back? I don't think that makes too much sense.

Comment: I don't want to disable the search when going back, I just want the page freshly reloaded, without the searchparameters in the url.